# Sum over a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL and have just started an internship at a company.  The company wants us to write some SQL that finds the weekly amount of hours worked. I was wondering how I could use SQL to find the sum of a column over a period of time like a week.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information such as table schemas and column meanings.

Answer (score 10):

I advice you a SQL manual.

There are 5 aggregation function in SQL

1. MIN - get minumum value of list
2. MAX - get maximum value of list
3. SUM - sum all not null value of list
4. AVG - get average al all not null value of list
5. COUNT - count all not null value of list

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 3):

```
select <DateColumn>,Sum(<columname>) from <Table> where <DateColumn> between <Date1> and <Date2)
Group by <DateColumn>
```